# Web service doesn't works in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, web-services

I have one (very basic) web service :

```
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
       Return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

And a method in a other solution that consume the web method HelloWorld :

```
        Private Function IsPorteur() As Boolean
            Dim isWearer As Boolean
            isWearer = False
            Try
                Dim MyService As New Service1() 'This line works fine
                MessageBox.Show(MyService.HelloWorld().ToString()) 'This line catch the error
                isWearer = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
            Return isWearer
        End Function
```

When I debug, I've this error  :

*An error message can not be displayed because an optional resource assembly container is not found*

What can I do to fix this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use an release-build? If so try a debug-build, maybe the exception will be useful.

Comment: I already use the debug-Build :/